# What is the state of internationalized email address support in 2020?

Tags: email, email-server

What major clients, servers, and commercial providers support internationalized email addresses in 2020, with what limitations? The existing information available on the Internet all seems to be a few years old, and isn't consistent.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "list"- question and therefor eligible for close votes...

But still I want to answer this: very few mail clients and servers really support internalized addresses. And some of them use different ways to encode these adresses, so that it is a pure game of luck whether a mail with special international characters will arrive or not.

I would hardly disencourage you to use such domains. They will very likely fail in being delivered.